# Desktop search engine for 11.04

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation

Just as the title says I'm searching for a great desktop search engine with nice Unity integration. Beagle used to be cool but for some reason it has been discontinued so it is out of the question. Finally the recommended app must be very fast when rendering search results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) is probably the most versatile at the moment. But the GUI is really not nice. If you have some skills, I think the developer would be happy for any [help](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/devel.html).

[Tracker](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Tracker) is an alternative, but it looks like there are no recent updates.

[DocFetcher](http://sourceforge.net/projects/docfetcher/) seems to be good as well, nicer GUI. But it is only for documents, not pictures, music, mails, ...

As of September 14 2011, [Google Desktop](http://googledesktop.blogspot.com) is no longer available for download, and existing installations will not be updated to include new features or fixes. Why that?

Answer (score 1):

[Tracker](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Tracker) is probably the best bet, will work with your regular "Search for files" application.

I would also recommend looking at [Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/). Although it is ugly and Qt based ( these two things aren't related ) it uses the awesome [Xapian](http://xapian.org/) search engine on the backend. It is a bit of a hassle to set it up and get it to index regularly but depending on your needs may be a good fit.

Comment: I'll definitely try Tracker and report. Thanks for the fast response

Answer (score 0):

you could try [google desktop](http://desktop.google.com/linux/)

i've used it before unity and it worked very well, i'm on kde at this stage so no idea about it's unity integration

Comment: the link gives a 404 error...

Comment: Well I trust Google with my data more than any other company so I'll go with your answer lol...

Comment: @richard i do mention that i don't know in my post